# Google Drive PHP Client render PDF?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to render a PDF from a service account (the file is shared with the service).

```
$pdf = $drive->files->get($file_id);
$pdf->downloadUrl
```

However, the resource is coming in with 401 Unauthorized. It's funny that I'm authorized to get the files and everything, but downloading the actual files is unauthorized?

I want to render this pdf inside my page, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloadurl and webcontentlink are not authorized, you have to send the access_token with the request:

```
$file->downloadUrl . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
```